# How to delete and reassign a dynamically allocated pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I'm taking a c++ programming course (we are still mostly using C) and we just got to dynamic allocation of memory. For one of my homeworks, I'm asked to create a function that transposes any given matrix. This function is given the following arguments as inputs: a pointer, in which are saved the matrix elements, the number of rows and of colunms. I would like this to be a *void* type function that changes the order of the stored elements without returning any new pointer.
I tried creating a new pointer, in which I save the elemtens in the correct order (using 2 *for* loops). Then what I would like to do is deallocating the original pointer (using the `delete` command), assinging it to the new pointer and finally deleting the new pointer.
This unfortunately does not work (some elements turn out to be random numbers), but I don't understand why.
I hope my code is more precise and clear than my explanation:

```
void Traspose(float *matrix, const int rows, const int cols ){

    auto *tras = new float [rows * cols];
    int  k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < rows * cols; j += cols){
            tras[k] = matrix[j + i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    delete[] matrix;
    matrix = tras;
    delete[] tras;
}
```

Comment: Two delete[], one new[] - That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Why do you want to *"finally deleting the new pointer"* - at that point you deleted all the memory, leaving you with nothing valid to point your pointer to

Comment: Change `void Traspose(float *matrix, const int rows, const int cols )` to `void Traspose(float *&matrix, const int rows, const int cols )` and don't `delete[] tras;` because it is now (at the tail end of the procedure) "owned" by `matrix` pointer.

Comment: Show how you call `Traspose` (shouldn't it be `Transpose` BTW?), then we can give further advice.

Comment: Who owns the `matrix` resource? You aren't showing it, but I assume the caller of your function performed a `new float [...]` for the `matrix` argument? If not, then that's a problem. If so, it's probably not a good idea for the `Transpose` function to dispose of a resource that was created by the caller in this case. And if you want to return a pointer through an argument, you need  `float **matrixPointer` or something like that, and then `*matrixPointer = tras`.  You should investigate using smart pointers in C++.

Comment: As Marc Gregoire says in "Professional C++, 5th Edition" (a book which I recommend you), prefer references to pointers. Pointers are hard to get right. You don't get them right, for example, when you seem to attempt to change what matrix is pointing to - but you don't. References save you ownership and object lifetime problems and are way, way safer.

Comment: As the matrix is 1D linear, the memory pointed to by `matrix` needs no "reallocation", or swapping. You only need temporary storage to do the transposition, then dump the result back into the memory pointed to by `matrix`.  Therefore, only `tras` needs to be deleted, and only after `std::copy(tras, tras+rows*cols, matrix);`. A `n*m` matrix transposed is just `m*n`. Same space requirements. Assuming you also fix your loop limits.

Comment: 1) Allocate temporary storage for computation.  2) Compute transpose into this temporary storage. 3) Copy the computed values from temporary storage to original storage  4) Remove temporary storage.  5) Done.  Those are the steps you could have followed, instead of doing the `delete[]`-tion of your original storage at the end of the function

Comment: I followed @WhozCraig advice and it works (thank you very much). To answer some of your question I initialized the matrix in a separate function using `float *matrix = new float [...]`. In my mind the = operator copyed the elements from `tras` to `matrix`, making `tras` useless to me and I thought deleting it would have been good practise for memory management. Thank you all for your answers, they made me understand why what I was doing it is wrong.

Comment: **You do not deallocate pointers.** You deallocate objects / memory blocks that you allocated. You use pointers to hold the addresses of those objects / memory blocks

Comment: Thank you very much @Eljay, I tryed what you suggested. It works and it's closer to what I had in mind. I tryed both `delete[] matrix;
    matrix = tras;` and simply `matrix = tras` and it seems to work both ways (I did not test this very extensively) . Do you think it makes a difference?

Answer (score 3):

All those lines are wrong:

```
delete[] matrix;
matrix = tras;
delete[] tras;
```

1. You didn't allocate `matrix` so you don't want do delete it.
2. You assign `tras` to `matrix` and then you `delete tras`, after that, `tras` points nowhere, nor does `matrix`.
3. `matrix = tras` is pointless anyway, because `matrix` is a local variable, and any changes to local variables are lost after the function ends.

Answer (score 1):

You're inventing a problem where none should exist.

A matrix AxB in dimension will transpose to a matrix BxA in size. While the dimensional difference is obvious the storage requirements might not be so. Your storage is identical.

Per the function signature, the change must be done in the same memory allocated to `matrix`. E.g., the results should be stored back into `matrix` memory. So, don't delete that memory; leave it alone. It is both large enough to hold the transposition, and owned by the caller regardless.

Rather, do this:

```
void Traspose(float *matrix, const int rows, const int cols)
{
    float *tras = new float[ rows * cols ];
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows * cols; j += cols)
            tras[k++] = matrix[j + i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<k; ++i)
        matrix[i] = tras[i];

    delete [] tras;
}
```

Note this gets quite a bit simpler (and safer) if the option to use the standard library algorithms and containers is on the table:

```
void Traspose(float *matrix, const int rows, const int cols)
{
    std::vector<float> tras;
    tras.reserve(rows*cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows * cols; j += cols)
            tras.emplace_back(matrix[j + i]);
    }
    std::copy(tras.begin(), tras.end(), matrix);
}
```

Finally, probably worth investigating in your spare time, there are algorithms to do this, even for non-square matrices, in place without temporary storage using *permutation chains*. I'll leave researching those as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a very basic exercise and I understand I'm making it more complicated than it is. My goal was to practice memory managment keeping track of the allocated memory and deleting it asap, but now i understand the limits of this example.